# hide divs if $[value] is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, the divs I have create some boxes, but if the value is not filled out, I don't want the box to show.  How would I do that?

Here's the divs I have:

```
<div id="age" class="leifbox" style="float:left;height:20px;text-align:center;margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;line-height:20px;">
{foreach $[user.mini_custom_field]}{if $[user.mini_custom_field.name] == "Age"}$[user.mini_custom_field.value] 
    {/if}{/foreach}
</div>

<div id="ability" class="leifbox" style="float:left;height:20px;text-align:center;margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;line-height:20px;">
{foreach $[user.mini_custom_field]}{if $[user.mini_custom_field.name] == "Abilities"}$[user.mini_custom_field.value]{/if}{/foreach}
</div>

<div id="element" class="leifbox" style="float:left;height:50px;text-align:center;margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;line-height:20px;">
{foreach $[user.mini_custom_field]}{if $[user.mini_custom_field.name] == "Element"}$[user.mini_custom_field.value]{/if}{/foreach}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
$('.leifbox:empty').hide();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/cMUFB/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

jquery each functiion fitst you to check if boxes are filled or not and then hide it.

```
    jQuery('.leifbox').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='') {   //to check boxes filled or not
            $(this).hide();   // hide it 
        } 
    }
```